# Schengen tourist visa confusion

Tags: applications, itineraries, schengen-visas

I am a permanent Resident of Canada and I am trying to understand the requirements of getting Schengen tourist visa.

I have not decided my exact dates of travel. I want to visit 6 to 7 countries. My appointment is with German Consulate for Schengen visa. All I know is I want to travel during the month of September or October for 2 weeks, depending on the best deal I get from travel agencies. How can I give them my itinerary or flight ticket details and accommodation details when I have still not decided on my exact dates?

I am also worried that, if I give hypothetical dates, they would issue a visa for just those 15 days and, later, if I cannot find any good deal for that period, it will be a waste.

Comment: You could submit a vague itinerary. They might accept it, but the risk is **very** high that it will be refused, especially for a first-time applicant. You could also make tentative plans and then make *minor* changes afterward, that's permitted with a Schengen visa. The risk would be that some border official finds that your changes are not really minor. So the best idea is to make more firm plans now.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to make up your mind before arranging the travel and arrange the travel before getting the visa.